# Is a typed vow of a Gentile binding?

Tags: gentiles, nedarim-shevuot, judaism

If a gentile in an email 'types' that he promises not to do something [1]doesn't use G-d's name 2]has no intention to keep the oath 3]but doesn't say bli neder either] is that vow binding? Some hold that writing counts as speaking. Others do not. Possibly even for those who rule that writing counts as speech, maybe typing is different. But does one need to find a rabbi to nullify that covenant?

Comment: Why are you singling out gentiles?

Comment: AFAIK the rules of vows do not apply to Gentiles. Even for a Jew that probably would not be a vow.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: See https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3760

Comment: **Ben Noah and his obligations regarding vows**: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44527/ben-noah-and-his-obligations-regarding-vows

Comment: It depends if the promise is monetary or religious. If the promise is religious then the religion itself holds the person to their promise and they should seek appropriate spiritual guidance from a mentor of that religion what to do. If the promise is monetary then if this is the only email ever sent regarding that matter and there were no further follow up actions from the other party then the email is not binding. However, if the other party acted based on the promise, then to the extent that the other party would now be compromised were the promise broken, the promise is binding.

Comment: It was a promise not to text a loved one. But the answers show how under different circumstances an oath or vow can be binding whilst in other places it does not. I understand laws for Jews and non-Jews differ. Thank you all! Very informative and a big lesson!